# [tag][!] Android Studio (not installed) [tag], Error when run flutter doctor on PC

Tags: flutter, android-studio

i have installed latest version of android studio and flutter.
but when i run *flutter doctor -v* it shows following error ***[!] Android Studio (not installed)***

flutter doctor output:

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.2.0, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19043.985], locale en-US)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[!] Android Studio (not installed)
[√] VS Code (version 1.56.2)
[√] Connected device (2 available)

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

PS: flutter & dart plugins installed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If android studio is installed correctly you can run the following command to change the path of android-studio installation:

`flutter config --android-studio-dir="ANDROID STUDIO PATH HERE"`

after this open a new terminal and run `flutter doctor` and you should see `[√] Android Studio (version x.x.x)`

Comment: Thanks. it worked! (i did this before. but without reopening a new terminal. probably that's why it didn't work)

Comment: yes you have to restart the terminal to make the changes take effect

Answer (score 0):

you can install flutter&dart plug，and then restart.

Answer (score 0):

android studio is installed correctly you can run the following command to change the path of the android-studio installation: >flutter config --android-studio-dir="C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio" // please use your Android Studio Path.